# Strange module auto complete behavior in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

[image]
See what I mean? At first it showed only `RB` and `absolute_import` as choices. STILL I was able to import `Gtk`. After that it showed a couple of more options. Still isn't a complete list of modules. If I import some other module (which I know of from the docs), then it appears in the list.

(I posted a similar problem previously but I wasn't able to explain it sufficiently well so I'm posting it again with better details)

Comment: you should add a link to your related question.

Answer (score 1):

Autocompletion **try** to determine the possible value of what you ask. gi.repository is probably defining stuff at import time so you cannot get everything right before actually importing it.

Like if you overwrote the `__getattr__` method of an object, you could make it respond to an arbitrary amount of key without being able to list them.

To know the exact reason you should dive into the code of [gi.repository](https://git.gnome.org/browse/?q=pygobj) (PyGI itself seem deprecated for 3 Years, replaced by pygobject), which from a quick readthrough is a completly dynamic binding of GObject that really build itself at import time by inspecting Gobject.

So I wouldn't be surprise that such an module have weird behavior at tab-completion.

Comment: Makes sense now. So using an IDE with PyGTK projects must be very tricky huh? Since code completion wouldn't work properly it would give wrong indications about module/classes not existing. Sure the code would run, but editing it would be a pain.