# Finding the code of classes I'm importing

Tags: python

In a shell executed by `python -v`, I put in `from gi.repository import Peas` and it gave me the directory of the module:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/repository
```

Now I went into this directory expecting to find subdirectoriessuch as `Peas`, `RB`, `Gtk` (which I can import) etc, but what's actually in it are

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/repository$ ls
__init__.py  __init__.pyc
```

That's it. How is Python importing Peas from this module when it has only an `__init__.py` file? How can I take a look at the code inside the `Peas` module?

Obviously I'm not understanding all this well. What's the explanation?

EDIT: Okay so this is very related to my earlier problem:
[Strange module auto complete behavior in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998369/strange-module-auto-complete-behavior-in-ipython)

So gi.repository is generated at import time since it's a dynamic binding. Makes sense.

But if I'm importing Peas from `gi.repository`, there still should be a way to check out what code is being imported right? Since I want to use PeasActivable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `repository` directory has a `__init__.py` file, `gi.repository` is a [package](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). This means that you can import from it and the package “root” will be the `__init__` file. If you had a file named `module.py` in the same directory, you could also import from `gi.repository.module`.

So your names `Peas`, `RB` and `Gtk` should be all defined within the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: No they aren't defined in `__init__.py`. The problem has something to do with the fact that it's a dynamic binding that builds itself by import time.